# How do you remove undesired snap packages from myapps.developer.ubuntu.com?

Tags: snapcraft

I went through the tutorial and it was great. However, it has you register a name and publish your newly minted snap to your online account.

How do I unregister the name and remove the snap from my account? I found the settings to "unpublish" and make "private", but I still don't want to waste a namespace or have the clutter on my account.

Is there a way to set things back to the way they were before I started the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Once a snap has been published and download it [cannot be removed](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-can-a-developer-remove-her-his-app-from-snap-store/512). As the linked post notes, this may change in the future but it's a fine line to walk: users who downloaded the app may be confused by being unable to reinstall.

Comment: Bit late sorry @Zak but how about this link or has it been resolved? https://dashboard.snapcraft.io/dev/snaps/